# Cant find out how to enable SSH on GoDaddy Windows Hosting

Tags: windows, ssh, remote-desktop, hosting, godaddy

I want to install python on a GoDaddy Windows Hosting , in order to do it I need to enable SSH , I tried to follow this tutorial :
https://www.godaddy.com/help/enable-ssh-4942
But I'm not able to find the place where I'm supposed to enter my mobile number , I only see my IP and an info that says that RDP has "login prohibited"
Any ideas ?

Comment: They said that link was for old accounts. Did you try https://www.godaddy.com/help/enable-ssh-16102 ?

Comment: Sorry, we can't help with specific web sites/services. Please contact your provider.

Answer (score 0):

*Here's my hip-shot, I hope it helps a little.*

It's safe to say this will only be possible if your Windows server has an SSH service on it, running and exposed to a port you can reach. I rarely use Windows for servers, but a quick search turned-up a random claim that http://www.freesshd.com is a good SSH server on Windows, I honestly wouldn't know.

So generally speaking, you need to:

1. Make sure an SSH server is installed on your machine.
2. Configure it for your needs.
3. Expose (Firewall exception) it on a port you can reach.

Hopefully someone else will leave a more direct answer for you. But this is my two-cents. Good luck.